# Create XML file from the dataset . Please Arrange node into the following Format

Tags: c#, xml

I fill my Dataset From certification table. Columns are the following

```
   Certification_name
   certification_id
   No_of_question,
   Question_name,
   Question_id
   Answer1
   Answer2
   Answer3
   Answer4
   Answer5
```

I want to Generate a Xml file like Following

```
  <Root>
   <Certification Certification_id="2" no_of_Question="10" certification_name="Test India">
     <question question_id="2" question_name="what is the Capital of India">
       <Answer1>Delhi</Answer1>
       <Answer2>New Delhi</Answer2>
       <Answer3>Mumbai</Answer3>
       <Answer4>Kolkata</Answer4>
    </question>
   </certification>
  </Root>
```

Please Help me...

My name is --Vikas Mishra
Emailid-brish.mishra@gmail.com

Comment: Please post what you have done so far and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

[Gelatin](http://wiki.github.com/knipknap/Gelatin/) was designed to solve this kind of problem.